# Android canvas: Is it possible to add images from gallery?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

In some paint apps or note taking apps, they will allow you to add text and images in addition to drawing stuff.

Now I know that I can create a custom view and override on touch events and build paths and draw them on canvas.

But what I don't know is this: In apps like mentioned above I am confused if they add images as image views or they add images directly drawn on canvas.

I mean do they create new imageview and set the gallery image to it, or they simply add the image directly to the canvas.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They draw it directly to the Canvas.  Notice the Canvas class (which is how Views draw) has a drawBitmap and drawText functions.  Generally in a drawing app the entire area you draw on will be just 1 view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but just to understand when we add stuff to the canvas like image , text , path ... We need to reference them somehow with a certain id, in order to drag them or click them...so how can we give them ids?

Comment: Any kind of dragging you'd need to implement totally yourself.

Comment: yes I understand but lets say I added 4 images from the gallery to the canvas, then how do I let the canvas know what image I touched or interacted with?

Comment: You'd have to do all of that.  You'd put a touch handler on the view, you'd have to remember what images are where, and you'd have to do hit detection.

Comment: so its easier to just add the images as normal views instead of sticking them to the canvas?

Comment: No, probably not.  But you're trying to do fairly advanced functionality, that means you're going to need to actually write some code.\

Comment: Yes I know that but I am confused, why these drawing apps don't just add images as views...because then detection of images will be much simpler than calculating probability areas and hit detection.

Comment: Because hit detection for images is fairly simple, and using different views makes a lot of things harder (compositing for storing to disk, z ordering, drawing on top of those bitmaps, etc)

Comment: Ahh I see, so do you have any advice on how I can go with detecting stuff on canvas and moving it?

Comment: You keep a List of graphical elements which have an x,y, width, and height of where they are on screen (and of course a reference to the object itself-  bitmap or string).  Hit detection is then just walking the list and seeing if the x,y of the touch down event is between x and x+width and y and y+height.

Comment: Ahh thats a great idea......but in a case where we have 3 images on same position they will have same coordinates?

Comment: Then you don't terminate your walk on the first match, but remember the best match and use a secondary criteria to choose.  Possibly z order.  Or choose the smallest image, on the theory that if you wanted the bigger one you'd have tapped on part that isn't overlapped.

Comment: These are very good and smart ideas you thought of thank you very much, this means that after I successfully detect the position I look it up in something like a map or so....to see the object associated with it and then I just translate that object?